# How to sort each column in a table and display highest value in each column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with data as follows:

```
Emp id, salary,deptid 
1,1000,1
2,500,3
3,1500,2
4,5000,2
5,3000,8
8,2000,5
7, 3500,1
9,3000,2
```

I need to sort each column in a table and display highest value in each column. So the output would look like below:

```
Empid,salary,deptid 
9,5000,8
```

Create table statement attached for convenience.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(empid INT, salary INT, deptid INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1000,1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,500,3);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(3,1500,2);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(4,5000,2);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(5,3000,8);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(8,2000,5);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(7, 3500,1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(9,3000,2);
```

It is in Oracle.

Comment: And you tried this sql statement: `select ... from t1 ...`. Where is it?

Comment: My bad. I interpreted this to be a aggregation problem which is definitely not the case here. @forpas soln opened the eyes for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not about sorting.
You want the max value of each column:

```
SLEECT MAX(empid) empid, 
       MAX(salary) salary, 
       MAX(deptid) deptid 
FROM t1
```